# Problems while installing kexi (kde) or badly installed?

Tags: kde

I'm following the instructions to install Kexi on [their website for Linux](https://community.kde.org/Kexi/Snapshots#Linux). But I get the following error:

```
$ flatpak remote-add kde http://distribute.kde.org/flatpak-apps-testing
error: Remote kde already exists

$ flatpak --filesystem=$HOME run org.kde.kexi-stable
error: app/org.kde.kexi-stable/i386/master not installed
```

Is this due to a different version of kexi? I would like to install the latest stable version.

Comment: What was the result of the flatpak install... command?

Comment: pp@acerlaptop:~/Downloads/arduino/arduino-1.8.9$ flatpak install kde org.kde.kexi-stable
Looking for matches…
error: Unable to load summary from remote kde: GPG signatures found, but none are in trusted keyring

Comment: I see them in my installed apps list:kde-runtime     install
kde-runtime-data    install
kde-style-breeze    install
kde-style-breeze-qt4    install
kdelibs-bin     install
kdelibs5-data     install
kdelibs5-plugins    install

Comment: What are your Ubuntu release and version (as in variant/derivative)?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial